# How to select with a variable in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, count

I need some help with my select.

```
SELECT
    bpasession.sessionnumber, 
    bpasession.sessionid, 
    bparesource.name, 
    bpaprocess.name, 
    bpastatus.description, 
    bpasession.startdatetime, 
    bpasession.enddatetime, 
    REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(5), 
                    DATEDIFF(ss, bpasession.startdatetime, bpasession.enddatetime)/ 3600) + ':' + 
                    STR(CONVERT(varchar(5), DATEDIFF(ss, bpasession.startdatetime, bpasession.enddatetime) % 3600 / 60), 2) + ':' + 
                    STR(CONVERT(varchar(5), DATEDIFF(ss, bpasession.startdatetime, bpasession.enddatetime) % 60), 2), ' ', '0'),
    (SELECT COUNT(BPAWorkQueueItem.id) 
     FROM BPAWorkQueueItem 
     WHERE BPAWorkQueueItem.sessionid = '(bpasession.sessionid line variable) ex. D7917C6F-E9D4-48E4-B7AE-53EEE6D18616') AS x
FROM
    BPAProcess, 
    BPAStatus, 
    BPASession, 
    BPAResource
WHERE
    bpastatus.statusid = bpasession.statusid 
    AND bpasession.processid = bpaprocess.processid
    AND bpasession.runningresourceid = BPAResource.resourceid   
    AND startdatetime >= '2021-12-01' 
ORDER BY
    bpasession.sessionnumber DESC
```

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJ8r0.jpg)

I would like to put a dynamic variable to be added to the select counter. Each row of my query has a different sessionid and it would be added to the query to count the elements it has in the workqueue items with the same sessionid.

How do I do that?

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server are completely different products; which one are you *really* using? Also it's *2021*, the ANSI-92 explicit JOIN syntax has been around for **29 Years**, it's *long* past time you adopted it. [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Start properly describing your issue - I read the last part and I really can not understand what you try to do. There is no need for a variable to get a hardcoded output in an additional column.

Comment: Sample data and expected output would help immensely. Side point: that complex date calculation looks like it should just be `CAST(... AS time)`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    bpasession.sessionnumber, 
    bpasession.sessionid, 
    bparesource.name, 
    bpaprocess.name, 
    bpastatus.description, 
    bpasession.startdatetime, 
    bpasession.enddatetime, 
    REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(5), 
                    DATEDIFF(ss, bpasession.startdatetime, bpasession.enddatetime)/ 3600) + ':' + 
                    STR(CONVERT(varchar(5), DATEDIFF(ss, bpasession.startdatetime, bpasession.enddatetime) % 3600 / 60), 2) + ':' + 
                    STR(CONVERT(varchar(5), DATEDIFF(ss, bpasession.startdatetime, bpasession.enddatetime) % 60), 2), ' ', '0'),
    (SELECT COUNT(BPAWorkQueueItem.id) 
     FROM BPAWorkQueueItem 
     WHERE BPAWorkQueueItem.sessionid = bpasession.sessionid) AS x
FROM
    BPAProcess, 
    BPAStatus, 
    BPASession, 
    BPAResource
WHERE
    bpastatus.statusid = bpasession.statusid 
    AND bpasession.processid = bpaprocess.processid
    AND bpasession.runningresourceid = BPAResource.resourceid   
    AND startdatetime >= '2021-12-01' 
ORDER BY
    bpasession.sessionnumber DESC
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).